# Neo Circuits-like game without Flash?

Tags: game

There's a great strategy game called [Neo Circuits](http://armorgames.com/play/12821/neo-circuit?rt=l). It's written in Flash, so it does not run anywhere anymore.

Because of neopets and keyword inflation, it's barely googlable these days.

Is there a similar game that doesn't use Flash? Android, Windows, Mac OS and web all work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I just played NeoCircuits, and it immediately reminded me of a game that I've played before with my kids: [**PWN**](http://www.82apps.com/pwn/)

PWN has all of the same features as NeoCircuts, plus a series of characters & items to improve / unlock!

Currently it supports both Apple & Mac App Stores, but it looks like they're looking to expand it, from their site: "I'm currently porting PWN to a bunch of other platforms."

Have fun!